# iOS Swift AES Encryption and Decryption found nil?

Tags: ios, encryption, cryptography, aes, swift2

Under the **Xcode 7.3.1** and **Swift 2.2**

I'm trying an AES Encryption and Decryption

Here is the AES code and **extension the type String**:

```
func aesEncrypt(key:String, iv:String, options:Int = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding) -> String? {
    if let keyData = key.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
    data = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
    cryptData = NSMutableData(length: Int((data.length)) + kCCBlockSizeAES128) {

        let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)
        let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
        let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
        let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(options)

        var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

        let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
            algoritm,
            options,
            keyData.bytes, keyLength,
            iv,
            data.bytes, data.length,
            cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
            &numBytesEncrypted)

        if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
            cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
            let base64cryptString = cryptData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
            return base64cryptString
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func aesDecrypt(key:String, iv:String, options:Int = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding) -> String? {
    if let keyData = key.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
    data = NSData(base64EncodedString: self, options: .IgnoreUnknownCharacters),
    cryptData = NSMutableData(length: Int((data.length)) + kCCBlockSizeAES128) {

        let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)
        let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCDecrypt)
        let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
        let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(options)

        var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

        let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
            algoritm,
            options,
            keyData.bytes, keyLength,
            iv,
            data.bytes, data.length,
            cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
            &numBytesEncrypted)

        if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
            cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
            let unencryptedMessage = String(data: cryptData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            return unencryptedMessage
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
return nil
}
```

After I extension the function Encryption and Decryption, I make some test in unit test.

But I got an error!

Here is my unit test :

```
func test() {
    let testA: String = "Hello"
    let keyString = "1"
    let ivString = "2"

    let testB: String = testA.aesEncrypt(keyString, iv:ivString)!
    let testC: String = testB.aesDecrypt(keyString, iv: ivString)!  <- Error
    print(testB)
    print(testC)

}
```

Error Contents:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The Error Screen :

[image]

Is there anyone have the same problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: Where is the extension code? Don't use an extension, create an encryption class and pass in the string to be encrypted. The name aesEncrypt is not sufficiently defined to add to the String class.

Comment: Thanks, man. I solved it. The length of the key and iv is not correct!